# Visual Studio shows no references on all my routines

Tags: c#, visual-studio

`References` above every routine:

[image: preview]

I've pulled an old project out of a source repository and loaded it into the same version Visual Studio environment that it's built in.

I couldn't run the project as it comes up with `TypeInitializationException` on the first instance where a variable is given a value. There's a clue that all the references show `- references` above every routine in the project. I can't work out what's going on.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Post the actual exception or compilation errors and the code that throws them. It doesn't matter *at all* what CodeLens shows or doesn't show. That's not a clue, that's just a delay in Visual Studio's analyzer. Older VS versions were buggier and slowerr. Right now there's no information in the question except `TypeInitializationException`

Comment: BTW you don't need to use an old VS version to compile a .NET project. You do need the libraries and NuGet packages the project needs. `TypeInitializationException` may mean there's a missing library

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos. Given the knowledge that CodeLens has nothing to do with it - which I had to delete the .vs folder and .suo file to get it working again - I was able to focus on other reasons.

My TypeInitializationException had two stacked inner exceptions that pointed me to a third party GPIB resource driver that was not installed on the computer.